# Get days on basis of Sum of values of

Tags: discrete-mathematics, contest-math

Lets suppose i have list of days :

- Sun - 1
- Mon - 2
- Tue - 4
- Wed - 8
- Thu - 16
- Fri - 32
- Sat - 64

Now user can select one or more then one from checklist .My database just storing the sum of days (Example: if user selected sun and mon then value is getting stored in database is 3)
.now i want to show user days he selected. What will be the formula to compute this.

Comment: Your computer stores numbers in binary, each of these values is a single binary bit and you can check for a single bit by using the logical AND function so for example using C `if (x & 1 == 1)` they selected Sunday similarly `if (x & 2 == 2)` the selected Monday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Write the sum of days in binary.

Any integer $n$ from $0$ to $127$ can be uniquely written as $$n=a_0\cdot 1 + a_1\cdot 2 + a_2\cdot 4 + a_3\cdot 8 + a_5\cdot 16 + a_6\cdot 32 + a_7\cdot 64$$
where $a_i\in\{0,1\}$. In binary, $n$ is then written as $$n=a_7a_6a_5a_4a_3a_2a_1a_0.$$

Simply looking at the digits of the binary expression of $n$ then gives you the days that were selected.

Comment: Can u help in brief please .How i will break binary number to Diff values.